# How Profile views are counted? Is it counted on Hover of my Profile pic?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, views, profile-picture

Is profile view gets counted if a user actually Sees my profile page on stackoverflow.com,Or even if he just hovers on my profile pic ,then also Count is increased? thanks

Comment: Count of IP addrs that made an http request for your profile? What does hovering have to do with anything?

Comment: Can you see PHP icon .Its my profile photo. So if you Hover / take your mouse over it, you get my Profile info in short like "I am web dev...." etc. So does that count as profile view?I mean without going to my page.

Comment: Oh, then the answer is no.

Comment: @bjb568 thanx man,you saved my life

Comment: if a person visited a profile from same ip address twice - than will the count increase by 2 or it will just remain 1 ?

Comment: @Rohit What do u think ? **:)**

Comment: It should and it is remaining 1. But IP address gets changed regularly. I want unique profile views count to measure my profile popularity/impact.

Comment: They have Unique count Only. Try to going on Your profile page and hit F5 200000 times you will still have only 1 View count. I tried