# Can I know who viewed my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, views

First of all, **It's not a Feature Request!!**

I think it's a question never been asked before on the site.

Knowing the names of Stack Exchange users, who have viewed my Profile!
I know that there is no such link in own profile. So, is there any support for that as such.

If not then what are the reasons behind it?

There are other related questions like,

1. [how-profile-views-are-counted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261133/how-profile-views-are-counted-is-it-counted-on-hover-of-my-profile-pic)
2. [does-profile-views-include-me-looking-at-my-own-profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289261/does-profile-views-include-me-looking-at-my-own-profile)
3. [badge-for-profile-views-must-be-in-so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260546/badge-for-profile-views-must-be-in-so)
4. [how-can-i-know-who-has-voted-down-my-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266485/how-can-i-know-who-has-voted-down-my-question)

But here I am asking here is something different!

Comment: Downvoters, please consider to comment for that!

Comment: There are requests for this but they seem all to be on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161325/where-can-i-find-who-viewed-my-profile-or-voted-on-my-questions, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60508/how-can-i-figure-out-who-has-visited-my-profile

Comment: so I am correct that it's not asked before on **THIS site**! but here all users don't seem to even comment when downvote any question :(

Comment: Have my downvote in case this turns into a feature request...

Comment: I don't see what utility this would serve. I can understand why it's good to know who viewed your LinkedIn or Careers profile, but not SO. I think this would mainly be used to escalate revenge downvoting.

Comment: I agree with Bill the Lizard; I don't see how this would help advance the mission of the site or even be helpful to users in general. Even in the best case scenario I can think of, this is a useless feature.

Answer (score 20):

No you can't.

This information is not available to users, not even moderators.

I would even suspect that it's not available to employees without direct database access and then only if the information is actually stored.

Unless there's a use case for it I would suspect that the information isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: Given other meta posts I've read back awhile, I *guess* that it is available by digging and reprocessing log files. It is labor intensive and rarely done and a real pita to do. It has been hinted at in questions of digging data on the strength of the meta effect (which requires log processing). But you are indeed right that this isn't stored anywhere that someone could say "ChrisF looked at my profile on..." with a quick query.

Comment: There is a question, Did you mean the employees contain the developers? I can't believe, backend developers, DevOps specialists and system administrators have access to the DataBase. with a simple query, they can see who viewed someone's profile.

Comment: @AmerllicA only if that information is actually stored.

Answer (score 7):

No.

**Reasoning:**

After reading all of the comments, Bill the Lizard has a very good point about the misuse of knowing who viewed your profile: "I think this would mainly be used to escalate revenge downvoting.".

In my personal experience with StackOverflow, it is **best** not to know **who** downvoted you or who is constantly looking at your profile and stick to following the rules of StackOverflow for the best experience possible.

Plus, I am sure users like Jon Skeet and moderators such as Bill would be bombarded with notifications of users constantly viewing their profiles.

**Other Concerns:**

Major social websites such as Facebook face privacy concerns all the time and articles about "apps users can install to track user views" such as this one: http://www.ibtimes.com/trying-find-out-who-looks-your-facebook-profile-stop-it-see-whos-stalking-you-apps-lead-1647450.